# Ratio test using limit superior and inferior

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Concerning the ration test for series, I need to prove that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}q_n>1$, with $q_n$ being the quotient sequence, implies divergence. We've already proven that $q_n\geq1$ for almost all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ implies divergence, so could you day that by $\liminf{n\to\infty}q_n>1$, $q_n>1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and would this not straightly imply $q_n\geq 1$, i.e. divergence. Why would I then need the strictly greater?

Also, what would be a counter example to the fact that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}q_n>1$ does not suffice for this.

Comment: a) Yes (not "all but "almost all", of course). b) $\sum_{k\ge 1} (3+(-1)^k)^{-k}$